# What does each term of the deformation gradient tensor represent?

Tags: terminology, differentiation, continuum-mechanics

I am taking a course in introductory continuum mechanics, and we were being taught displacement and deformation gradients. I'm having a tough time understanding what each term of the deformation gradient means? e.g., for a 2D case, what does the element in the first row and first column mean?

I understand that it somehow relates deformations in the reference and deformed configurations, but I don't understand how the directions in the numerator and denominator come into play.

Comment: I suggest that you rephrase your question to ask just whatever is in your postscript

Answer (score 0):

Let $dx_i$ be the Cartesian differential position vector components joining two neighboring material points in the deformed configuration of a body and let $dX_j$ be the Cartesian differential position vector components joining  the same two material points in the undeformed configuration of the body (say, at time zero).  Then, using the Einstein summation convention $$dx_i=\left(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial X_j}\right)dX_j$$The quantities in parenthesis are the component of the deformation gradient tensor.  This tensor maps a differential position vector joining two material points in the undeformed configuration of a body into the differential position vector between the same two material points in the deformed configuration of the body.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to give an answer, first we need to agree on the fact that a tensor doesn't have rows or columns, but it's an absolute mathematical object that is independent on the choice of the coordinates used.

Now, if we agree on this, we can look at the deformation gradient tensor as a tensor that links the Lagrangian description of the problem (we follow the motion of each material particle of the medium; these particles are "labelled" with the vector $\mathbf{x}_0$) and the Eulerian description of the problem. The position in space $\mathbf{x}$ of a point labelled with the Lagrangian coordinate $\mathbf{x}_0$, can be written as a function of the Lagrangian coordinate and time,

$\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{x}_0, t)$.

Looking at a configuration at a specific time, you can write the differential of $\mathbf{x}$ as

$d \mathbf{x} = d \mathbf{x}_0 \cdot \mathbf{\nabla}_0 \mathbf{x}$,

where $\nabla_0 \mathbf{x}$ is the deformation gradient tensor that relates a elementary vector in the Lagrangian coordinates $d\mathbf{x}_0$ with the elementary vector in the physical space $d\mathbf{x}$.

Now, if we introduce a set of Cartesian coordinates, so that the basis is orthogonal, we can write

$d\mathbf{x}_0 = dx_0^i \ \mathbf{e}_i$

$\nabla_0 \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{e}_i \otimes  \dfrac{\partial x^j \mathbf{e}_j}{\partial x_0^i} = \mathbf{e}_i \otimes \mathbf{e}_j \dfrac{\partial x^j}{\partial x_0^i}$

so that

$d\mathbf{x} = d\mathbf{x}_0 \cdot \nabla_0 \mathbf{x} = 
dx_0^i \ \underbrace{\mathbf{e}_i \cdot \mathbf{e}_j}_{= \delta_{ij}} \otimes \mathbf{e}_k \dfrac{\partial x^k}{\partial x_0^j} = 
\mathbf{e}_k dx_0^i \dfrac{\partial x^k}{\partial x_0^i} = \mathbf{e}_k dx^k
$,

i.e. the differential of the $k$-th Cartesian physical coordinate reads
$dx^k =  dx_0^i \dfrac{\partial x^k}{\partial x_0^i}$.